# application in excel that can be connected to some application in iPad?

Tags: excel, ipad

Could someone tell me what should be used (kind of software or some application in excel like powerview) that dashboard or decision tool created in excel can be connected via internet to something that can be seen on iPad and this something is updated in accordance with any changes in original excel file?

Comment: Sorry but your question, as presented, is "off-topic" for SO - you want a recommendation on software but that isn't what we do.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Excel app in the App Store and sign in with your Microsoft ID, you must have a subscription to Office 365 inorder to download it onto other device. You'd also be able to connect via OneDrive by downloading that app and having the xls file on there and you'd be able to retrieve changes anywhere you are connected to the Internet. You also have access to the free web app that can be used in a web browser, but that won't work on the iPad, usually need to download the Excel App.